# Chrome is marking my website as dangerous and stating your password may be compromised

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, authentication

Recently I created my first website (self-taught), which is hosted on **Firebase**.

Now that I added **Firebase Email/Password** authentication for my users here:
https://ottigan.com/dailyChecking/main.html

Whenever anyone, using **Chrome browser**, inputs a *password that they use anywhere else*, Chrome instantly marks my website as Dangerous: [screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDaN3.png).

**Chrome setting** which triggers the issue: **Settings** => **Privacy and security** => **Security** => **Enhanced Protection**

I have checked my site for security/malware issues (nothing came up) on:

- transparencyreport.google.com
- sitecheck.sucuri.net

Could this be related to me having **poorly constructed login form?** Considering most of authentication is handled with the Firebase API in my client side .js? When creating my login form, I did try to follow Firebase documentation and the suggestions provided: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/save-forms

During the past couple of months, there have been numerous threads on https://support.google.com/chrome/
People complaining about a similar issue, but it seems like it never goes anywhere.

Some examples:

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/28400888?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/42621564?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/38218347?hl=en

In addition there is a closed Chromium Bug report seemingly related to the issue I am struggling with:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068202

I would appreciate any help that I could get! My first stackoverflow post... CHECK! :)

Comment: In [this bug thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/42621564?hl=en), they are internally reviewing sites and marking them safe, so perhaps just use firefox for development and ask https://bugs.chromium.org/u/1839548693/ to help you get your production site reviewed and marked safe. This is a personal advice to help poster out and not a long term solution, it shouldn't halt the process of finding and fixing the bug (if it exists).

Comment: That could work, wasn't sure if it is appropriate messaging the specific individual, considering the bug was closed. But I've tried changing the way users access my website www. version or non-www. Tried messing with autocomplete attributes, adding labels to adhere to the status quo. And even preventDefault on submit to mimick a direct POST method to the server.

Comment: then start another bug report and cite the earlier one and perhaps those relevant contributors (?)